# Get actual product from array in struct

Tags: ios, swift

I have code:

```
struct CountedProduct
{
    var productCode: String
    var productCountable: Bool


    init(productCode: String, productCountable: Bool, pricePerKg: Decimal, weightYieldInPercent: Decimal?, pricePerPortion: Decimal, countPerPortion: Int?, weightPerPortionInGrams: Decimal?, pieceWeight: Decimal?) {
        self.productCode = productCode
        self.productCountable = productCountable
    }

}


struct Calculator
{  
    var type: String?

    let createTime: Double
    var products : [CountedProduct]?
    var activeProduct: Int? 



public mutating func getActiveProducts(index: Int)->CountedProduct{
        for (id, element) in (products?.enumerated())!{
            if id == index {
                return  (self.products?[index])!
            }
        }
        return activeProduct
    }

}
```

I have error in function `getActiveProducts`

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int?' to return type 'CountedProduct'

I need to download the currently selected product in products: `[CountedProduct]`.
The product table in products can be empty

Comment: As you code snippet, you defined `activeProduct` as `Int` type, not `CountedProduct` type. Expected return value of `getActiveProducts` is `CountedProduct`. So you can't cast return type to `CountedProduct` type when using `activeProduct` variable.

Comment: This is a simple compilation error, try to understand what the compiler is telling you and examine your code _before_ posting on stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is pretty clear:

At the end of the function you are returning `activeProduct` which is an `Int` but the return value is `CountedProduct`

I recommend to declare `products` as non-optional to get rid of the ugly question marks

```
var products = [CountedProduct]()
```

and to use this improved function:

```
public func getActiveProduct(index: Int) -> CountedProduct? {
        guard index < products.count else { return nil }
        return products[index]
    }
}
```

You don't need a loop since you know the index but you have to check if the index is less than the number of items in the array. And actually the function is not `mutating` and the naming should be in singular form because you are going to return only one object

Answer (score 0):

Your `activeProduct` is integer type and you are return `activeProduct` in `getActiveProducts` method which return type is `CountedProduct` so such kind of error occured.

You can solve this error as below

```
var activeProduct: CountedProduct?
```